# this week in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, datetime

I try to find an answer but without result

the problem is:

in sunday function return date for Monday next week

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Moscow'));
$date->setTimestamp(strtotime('Monday this week'));

echo $date->format("d.m.Y");
```

but in other days (except Sunday) its return correct value of Monday.

I ever set locale manualy , which has a monday - the first day of week, but PHP "think" the Sunday is still firs day.  is it bug ?? or i do some wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be known idiosyncrasies with `strtotime`.  It's mentioned in the comments:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#108317

They don't mention different locales specifically but it would be extremely unsurprising if `strtotime()` does not correctly behave for `next/this week` under different locales.

Try `this Monday` or `next Monday` and see if one of those gets what you want.

Comment: this Monday give the same result , if i change my localtime to saturday - its correct )) now i "fix" it for special if statement for Sunday

Comment: That is probably the solution you will be stuck with.  PHP is full of horrible gotchas like this.